# SQL multiple table join subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I use a sub query for just the invite table? I'd like all records from `patient_profiles` and for the invites join to use only records created after a specific date?

```
SELECT p.first_name,
COUNT(invites.invited_by_id)as invite_count
FROM patient_profiles AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN patient_profiles AS invites ON invites.invited_by_id = p.id
WHERE p.is_test = false AND AND invites.created_at >= '2017-10-16'::date 
GROUP BY p.first_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery.  Just move the date condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p.first_name,
       COUNT(invites.invited_by_id)as invite_count
FROM patient_profiles p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     patient_profiles invite
     ON invites.invited_by_id = p.id AND invites.created_at >= '2017-10-16'::date
WHERE p.is_test = false
GROUP BY p.first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVING`.

```
SELECT p.first_name, COUNT(invites.invited_by_id)as invite_count
FROM patient_profiles p
GROUP BY p.first_name
HAVING p.is_test = false AND p.created_at >= '2017-10-16'::date
```

Comment: this appears to filter all records based on the date, I'd only like the records for COUNT() to be filtered based on the date clause